# Characterization of $1.75$-flips

Tags: number-theory

Define a number to be a $1.75$-flip if multiplying it by $1.75$ gives the reverse of the number. For example, $12$ is a $1.75$-flip because $12\cdot 1.75=21$, which is the reverse of $12$. So far, I know that $1.75$-flips must start with $0, 1, 2, 3,$ or $4$.  I also know that all $1.75$-flips are multiples of $12.$

Here is a list of $1.75$-flips up to a billion:

$0, 12, 24, 36, 48, 132, 264, 396, 1212, 1332, 1452, 1572, 1692, 2304, 2424, 2544, 2664, 2784, 3516, 3636, 3756, 3876, 3996, 4608, 4728, 4848, 4968, 12012, 13332, 14652, 15972, 24024, 25344, 26664, 27984, 36036, 37356, 38676, 39996, 48048, 49368, 120012, 121212, 122412, 123612, 124812, 132132, 133332, 134532, 135732, 136932, 143052, 144252, 145452, 146652, 147852, 155172, 156372, 157572, 158772, 159972, 166092, 167292, 168492, 169692, 230304, 231504, 232704, 233904, 240024, 241224, 242424, 243624, 244824, 252144, 253344, 254544, 255744, 256944, 263064, 264264, 265464, 266664, 267864, 275184, 276384, 277584, 278784, 279984, 350316, 351516, 352716, 353916, 360036, 361236, 362436, 363636, 364836, 372156, 373356, 374556, 375756, 376956, 383076, 384276, 385476, 386676, 387876, 395196, 396396, 397596, 398796, 399996, 460608, 461808, 470328, 471528, 472728, 473928, 480048, 481248, 482448, 483648, 484848, 492168, 493368, 494568, 495768, 496968, 1200012, 1213212, 1226412, 1239612, 1320132, 1333332, 1346532, 1359732, 1440252, 1453452, 1466652, 1479852, 1560372, 1573572, 1586772, 1599972, 1680492, 1693692, 2306304, 2319504, 2400024, 2413224, 2426424, 2439624, 2520144, 2533344, 2546544, 2559744, 2640264, 2653464, 2666664, 2679864, 2760384, 2773584, 2786784, 2799984, 3506316, 3519516, 3600036, 3613236, 3626436, 3639636, 3720156, 3733356, 3746556, 3759756, 3840276, 3853476, 3866676, 3879876, 3960396, 3973596, 3986796, 3999996, 4706328, 4719528, 4800048, 4813248, 4826448, 4839648, 4920168, 4933368, 4946568, 4959768, 12000012, 12012012, 12024012, 12036012, 12048012, 12121212, 12133212, 12145212, 12157212, 12169212, 12230412, 12242412, 12254412, 12266412, 12278412, 12351612, 12363612, 12375612, 12387612, 12399612, 12460812, 12472812, 12484812, 12496812, 13200132, 13212132, 13224132, 13236132, 13248132, 13321332, 13333332, 13345332, 13357332, 13369332, 13430532, 13442532, 13454532, 13466532, 13478532, 13551732, 13563732, 13575732, 13587732, 13599732, 13660932, 13672932, 13684932, 13696932, 14303052, 14315052, 14327052, 14339052, 14400252, 14412252, 14424252, 14436252, 14448252, 14521452, 14533452, 14545452, 14557452, 14569452, 14630652, 14642652, 14654652, 14666652, 14678652, 14751852, 14763852, 14775852, 14787852, 14799852, 15503172, 15515172, 15527172, 15539172, 15600372, 15612372, 15624372, 15636372, 15648372, 15721572, 15733572, 15745572, 15757572, 15769572, 15830772, 15842772, 15854772, 15866772, 15878772, 15951972, 15963972, 15975972, 15987972, 15999972, 16606092, 16618092, 16703292, 16715292, 16727292, 16739292, 16800492, 16812492, 16824492, 16836492, 16848492, 16921692, 16933692, 16945692, 16957692, 16969692, 23030304, 23042304, 23054304, 23066304, 23078304, 23151504, 23163504, 23175504, 23187504, 23199504, 23260704, 23272704, 23284704, 23296704, 23381904, 23393904, 24000024, 24012024, 24024024, 24036024, 24048024, 24121224, 24133224, 24145224, 24157224, 24169224, 24230424, 24242424, 24254424, 24266424, 24278424, 24351624, 24363624, 24375624, 24387624, 24399624, 24460824, 24472824, 24484824, 24496824, 25200144, 25212144, 25224144, 25236144, 25248144, 25321344, 25333344, 25345344, 25357344, 25369344, 25430544, 25442544, 25454544, 25466544, 25478544, 25551744, 25563744, 25575744, 25587744, 25599744, 25660944, 25672944, 25684944, 25696944, 26303064, 26315064, 26327064, 26339064, 26400264, 26412264, 26424264, 26436264, 26448264, 26521464, 26533464, 26545464, 26557464, 26569464, 26630664, 26642664, 26654664, 26666664, 26678664, 26751864, 26763864, 26775864, 26787864, 26799864, 27503184, 27515184, 27527184, 27539184, 27600384, 27612384, 27624384, 27636384, 27648384, 27721584, 27733584, 27745584, 27757584, 27769584, 27830784, 27842784, 27854784, 27866784, 27878784, 27951984, 27963984, 27975984, 27987984, 27999984, 35030316, 35042316, 35054316, 35066316, 35078316, 35151516, 35163516, 35175516, 35187516, 35199516, 35260716, 35272716, 35284716, 35296716, 35381916, 35393916, 36000036, 36012036, 36024036, 36036036, 36048036, 36121236, 36133236, 36145236, 36157236, 36169236, 36230436, 36242436, 36254436, 36266436, 36278436, 36351636, 36363636, 36375636, 36387636, 36399636, 36460836, 36472836, 36484836, 36496836, 37200156, 37212156, 37224156, 37236156, 37248156, 37321356, 37333356, 37345356, 37357356, 37369356, 37430556, 37442556, 37454556, 37466556, 37478556, 37551756, 37563756, 37575756, 37587756, 37599756, 37660956, 37672956, 37684956, 37696956, 38303076, 38315076, 38327076, 38339076, 38400276, 38412276, 38424276, 38436276, 38448276, 38521476, 38533476, 38545476, 38557476, 38569476, 38630676, 38642676, 38654676, 38666676, 38678676, 38751876, 38763876, 38775876, 38787876, 38799876, 39503196, 39515196, 39527196, 39539196, 39600396, 39612396, 39624396, 39636396, 39648396, 39721596, 39733596, 39745596, 39757596, 39769596, 39830796, 39842796, 39854796, 39866796, 39878796, 39951996, 39963996, 39975996, 39987996, 39999996, 46060608, 46072608, 46084608, 46096608, 46181808, 46193808, 47030328, 47042328, 47054328, 47066328, 47078328, 47151528, 47163528, 47175528, 47187528, 47199528, 47260728, 47272728, 47284728, 47296728, 47381928, 47393928, 48000048, 48012048, 48024048, 48036048, 48048048, 48121248, 48133248, 48145248, 48157248, 48169248, 48230448, 48242448, 48254448, 48266448, 48278448, 48351648, 48363648, 48375648, 48387648, 48399648, 48460848, 48472848, 48484848, 48496848, 49200168, 49212168, 49224168, 49236168, 49248168, 49321368, 49333368, 49345368, 49357368, 49369368, 49430568, 49442568, 49454568, 49466568, 49478568, 49551768, 49563768, 49575768, 49587768, 49599768, 49660968, 49672968, 49684968, 49696968, 120000012, 120132012, 120264012, 120396012, 121201212, 121333212, 121465212, 121597212, 122402412, 122534412, 122666412, 122798412, 123603612, 123735612, 123867612, 123999612, 124804812, 124936812, 132000132, 132132132, 132264132, 132396132, 133201332, 133333332, 133465332, 133597332, 134402532, 134534532, 134666532, 134798532, 135603732, 135735732, 135867732, 135999732, 136804932, 136936932, 143063052, 143195052, 144000252, 144132252, 144264252, 144396252, 145201452, 145333452, 145465452, 145597452, 146402652, 146534652, 146666652, 146798652, 147603852, 147735852, 147867852, 147999852, 155063172, 155195172, 156000372, 156132372, 156264372, 156396372, 157201572, 157333572, 157465572, 157597572, 158402772, 158534772, 158666772, 158798772, 159603972, 159735972, 159867972, 159999972, 167063292, 167195292, 168000492, 168132492, 168264492, 168396492, 169201692, 169333692, 169465692, 169597692, 230402304, 230534304, 230666304, 230798304, 231603504, 231735504, 231867504, 231999504, 232804704, 232936704, 240000024, 240132024, 240264024, 240396024, 241201224, 241333224, 241465224, 241597224, 242402424, 242534424, 242666424, 242798424, 243603624, 243735624, 243867624, 243999624, 244804824, 244936824, 252000144, 252132144, 252264144, 252396144, 253201344, 253333344, 253465344, 253597344, 254402544, 254534544, 254666544, 254798544, 255603744, 255735744, 255867744, 255999744, 256804944, 256936944, 263063064, 263195064, 264000264, 264132264, 264264264, 264396264, 265201464, 265333464, 265465464, 265597464, 266402664, 266534664, 266666664, 266798664, 267603864, 267735864, 267867864, 267999864, 275063184, 275195184, 276000384, 276132384, 276264384, 276396384, 277201584, 277333584, 277465584, 277597584, 278402784, 278534784, 278666784, 278798784, 279603984, 279735984, 279867984, 279999984, 351735516, 351867516, 351999516, 352804716, 352936716, 360000036, 360132036, 360264036, 360396036, 361201236, 361333236, 361465236, 361597236, 362402436, 362534436, 362666436, 362798436, 363603636, 363735636, 363867636, 363999636, 364804836, 364936836, 372000156, 372132156, 372264156, 372396156, 373201356, 373333356, 373465356, 373597356, 374402556, 374534556, 374666556, 374798556,375603756, 375735756, 375867756, 375999756, 376804956,  376936956, 383063076, 383195076, 384000276, 384132276, 384264276, 384396276, 385201476, 385333476, 385465476, 385597476, 386402676, 386534676, 386666676, 386798676, 387603876, 387735876, 387867876, 387999876, 395063196, 395195196, 396000396, 396132396, 396264396, 396396396, 397201596, 397333596, 397465596, 397597596, 398402796, 398534796, 398666796, 398798796, 399603996, 399735996, 399867996, 399999996, 460804608, 460936608, 470402328, 470534328, 470666328, 470798328, 471603528, 471735528, 471867528, 471999528, 472804728, 472936728, 480000048, 480132048, 480264048, 480396048, 481201248, 481333248, 481465248, 481597248, 482402448, 482534448, 482666448, 482798448, 483603648, 483735648, 483867648, 483999648, 484804848, 484936848, 492000168, 492132168, 492264168, 492396168, 493201368, 493333368, 493465368, 493597368, 494402568, 494534568, 494666568, 494798568, 495603768, 495735768, 495867768, 495999768, 496804968, 496936968$

I have noticed that dividing some of these by $12$ gives a palindrome, but there are other numbers like $2304$ which do not exhibit that behavior.

What is a characterization/classification of $1.75$-flips?

Here's an example of a classification of $1.5$-flips:

Define a flippy palindrome as a palindrome using only the digits $0$ and $1$ such that $0$'s and $1$'s occur in contiguous blocks of size at least $2.$ Then $396x$ is a $1.5$-flip iff $x$ is a flippy palindrome.

They can also be classified using their really nice structure of being palidromic strings of $0, 4356, 43956, 439956, 4399956,$ etc.

Comment: $1$-flips are just palindromes.

Comment: $1.75$-flips seem unusually chaotic and hard to characterize.

Comment: It's obvious that all these values are multiples of $4$. Is there an obvious reason why they are also all multiples of $3$?

Comment: If you take the difference between a number and its reverse, you always get a multiple of $9.$

Answer (score 0):

A first step towards an answer:

Here are the above $1.75$-flips divided by $12$, giving all such numbers up to $10^8$:

$0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 22, 33, 101, 111, 121, 131, 141, 192, 202, 212, 222, 232, 293, 303, 313, 323, 333, 384, 394, 404, 414, 1001, 1111, 1221, 1331, 2002, 2112, 2222, 2332, 3003, 3113, 3223, 3333, 4004, 4114, 10001, 10101, 10201, 10301, 10401, 11011, 11111, 11211, 11311, 11411, 11921, 12021, 12121, 12221, 12321, 12931, 13031, 13131, 13231, 13331, 13841, 13941, 14041, 14141, 19192, 19292, 19392, 19492, 20002, 20102, 20202, 20302, 20402, 21012, 21112, 21212, 21312, 21412, 21922, 22022, 22122, 22222, 22322, 22932, 23032, 23132, 23232, 23332, 29193, 29293, 29393, 29493, 30003, 30103, 30203, 30303, 30403, 31013, 31113, 31213, 31313, 31413, 31923, 32023, 32123, 32223, 32323, 32933, 33033, 33133, 33233, 33333, 38384, 38484, 39194, 39294, 39394, 39494, 40004, 40104, 40204, 40304, 40404, 41014, 41114, 41214, 41314, 41414, 100001, 101101, 102201, 103301, 110011, 111111, 112211, 113311, 120021, 121121, 122221, 123321, 130031, 131131, 132231, 133331, 140041, 141141, 192192, 193292, 200002, 201102, 202202, 203302, 210012, 211112, 212212, 213312, 220022, 221122, 222222, 223322, 230032, 231132, 232232, 233332, 292193, 293293, 300003, 301103, 302203, 303303, 310013, 311113, 312213, 313313, 320023, 321123, 322223, 323323, 330033, 331133, 332233, 333333, 392194, 393294, 400004, 401104, 402204, 403304, 410014, 411114, 412214, 413314, 1000001, 1001001, 1002001, 1003001, 1004001, 1010101, 1011101, 1012101, 1013101, 1014101, 1019201, 1020201, 1021201, 1022201, 1023201, 1029301, 1030301, 1031301, 1032301, 1033301, 1038401, 1039401, 1040401, 1041401, 1100011, 1101011, 1102011, 1103011, 1104011, 1110111, 1111111, 1112111, 1113111, 1114111, 1119211, 1120211, 1121211, 1122211, 1123211, 1129311, 1130311, 1131311, 1132311, 1133311, 1138411, 1139411, 1140411, 1141411, 1191921, 1192921, 1193921, 1194921, 1200021, 1201021, 1202021, 1203021, 1204021, 1210121, 1211121, 1212121, 1213121, 1214121, 1219221, 1220221, 1221221, 1222221, 1223221, 1229321, 1230321, 1231321, 1232321, 1233321, 1291931, 1292931, 1293931, 1294931, 1300031, 1301031, 1302031, 1303031, 1304031, 1310131, 1311131, 1312131, 1313131, 1314131, 1319231, 1320231, 1321231, 1322231, 1323231, 1329331, 1330331, 1331331, 1332331, 1333331, 1383841, 1384841, 1391941, 1392941, 1393941, 1394941, 1400041, 1401041, 1402041, 1403041, 1404041, 1410141, 1411141, 1412141, 1413141, 1414141, 1919192, 1920192, 1921192, 1922192, 1923192, 1929292, 1930292, 1931292, 1932292, 1933292, 1938392, 1939392, 1940392, 1941392, 1948492, 1949492, 2000002, 2001002, 2002002, 2003002, 2004002, 2010102, 2011102, 2012102, 2013102, 2014102, 2019202, 2020202, 2021202, 2022202, 2023202, 2029302, 2030302, 2031302, 2032302, 2033302, 2038402, 2039402, 2040402, 2041402, 2100012, 2101012, 2102012, 2103012, 2104012, 2110112, 2111112, 2112112, 2113112, 2114112, 2119212, 2120212, 2121212, 2122212, 2123212, 2129312, 2130312, 2131312, 2132312, 2133312, 2138412, 2139412, 2140412, 2141412, 2191922, 2192922, 2193922, 2194922, 2200022, 2201022, 2202022, 2203022, 2204022, 2210122, 2211122, 2212122, 2213122, 2214122, 2219222, 2220222, 2221222, 2222222, 2223222, 2229322, 2230322, 2231322, 2232322, 2233322, 2291932, 2292932, 2293932, 2294932, 2300032, 2301032, 2302032, 2303032, 2304032, 2310132, 2311132, 2312132, 2313132, 2314132, 2319232, 2320232, 2321232, 2322232, 2323232, 2329332, 2330332, 2331332, 2332332, 2333332, 2919193, 2920193, 2921193, 2922193, 2923193, 2929293, 2930293, 2931293, 2932293, 2933293, 2938393, 2939393, 2940393, 2941393, 2948493, 2949493, 3000003, 3001003, 3002003, 3003003, 3004003, 3010103, 3011103, 3012103, 3013103, 3014103, 3019203, 3020203, 3021203, 3022203, 3023203, 3029303, 3030303, 3031303, 3032303, 3033303, 3038403, 3039403, 3040403, 3041403, 3100013, 3101013, 3102013, 3103013, 3104013, 3110113, 3111113, 3112113, 3113113, 3114113, 3119213, 3120213, 3121213, 3122213, 3123213, 3129313, 3130313, 3131313, 3132313, 3133313, 3138413, 3139413, 3140413, 3141413, 3191923, 3192923, 3193923, 3194923, 3200023, 3201023, 3202023, 3203023, 3204023, 3210123, 3211123, 3212123, 3213123, 3214123, 3219223, 3220223, 3221223, 3222223, 3223223, 3229323, 3230323, 3231323, 3232323, 3233323, 3291933, 3292933, 3293933, 3294933, 3300033, 3301033, 3302033, 3303033, 3304033, 3310133, 3311133, 3312133, 3313133, 3314133, 3319233, 3320233, 3321233, 3322233, 3323233, 3329333, 3330333, 3331333, 3332333, 3333333, 3838384, 3839384, 3840384, 3841384, 3848484, 3849484, 3919194, 3920194, 3921194, 3922194, 3923194, 3929294, 3930294, 3931294, 3932294, 3933294, 3938394, 3939394, 3940394, 3941394, 3948494, 3949494, 4000004, 4001004, 4002004, 4003004, 4004004, 4010104, 4011104, 4012104, 4013104, 4014104, 4019204, 4020204, 4021204, 4022204, 4023204, 4029304, 4030304, 4031304, 4032304, 4033304, 4038404, 4039404, 4040404, 4041404, 4100014, 4101014, 4102014, 4103014, 4104014, 4110114, 4111114, 4112114, 4113114, 4114114, 4119214, 4120214, 4121214, 4122214, 4123214, 4129314, 4130314, 4131314, 4132314, 4133314, 4138414, 4139414, 4140414, 4141414, 10000001, 10011001, 10022001, 10033001, 10100101, 10111101, 10122101, 10133101, 10200201, 10211201, 10222201, 10233201, 10300301, 10311301, 10322301, 10333301, 10400401, 10411401, 11000011, 11011011, 11022011, 11033011, 11100111, 11111111, 11122111, 11133111, 11200211, 11211211, 11222211, 11233211, 11300311, 11311311, 11322311, 11333311, 11400411, 11411411, 11921921, 11932921, 12000021, 12011021, 12022021, 12033021, 12100121, 12111121, 12122121, 12133121, 12200221, 12211221, 12222221, 12233221, 12300321, 12311321, 12322321, 12333321, 12921931, 12932931, 13000031, 13011031, 13022031, 13033031, 13100131, 13111131, 13122131, 13133131, 13200231, 13211231, 13222231, 13233231, 13300331, 13311331, 13322331, 13333331, 13921941, 13932941, 14000041, 14011041, 14022041, 14033041, 14100141, 14111141, 14122141, 14133141, 19200192, 19211192, 19222192, 19233192, 19300292, 19311292, 19322292, 19333292, 19400392, 19411392, 20000002, 20011002, 20022002, 20033002, 20100102, 20111102, 20122102, 20133102, 20200202, 20211202, 20222202, 20233202, 20300302, 20311302, 20322302, 20333302, 20400402, 20411402, 21000012, 21011012, 21022012, 21033012, 21100112, 21111112, 21122112, 21133112, 21200212, 21211212, 21222212, 21233212, 21300312, 21311312, 21322312, 21333312, 21400412, 21411412, 21921922, 21932922, 22000022, 22011022, 22022022, 22033022, 22100122, 22111122, 22122122, 22133122, 22200222, 22211222, 22222222, 22233222, 22300322, 22311322, 22322322, 22333322, 22921932, 22932932, 23000032, 23011032, 23022032, 23033032, 23100132, 23111132, 23122132, 23133132, 23200232, 23211232, 23222232, 23233232, 23300332, 23311332, 23322332, 23333332, 29311293, 29322293, 29333293, 29400393, 29411393, 30000003, 30011003, 30022003, 30033003, 30100103, 30111103, 30122103, 30133103, 30200203, 30211203, 30222203, 30233203, 30300303, 30311303, 30322303, 30333303, 30400403, 30411403, 31000013, 31011013, 31022013, 31033013, 31100113, 31111113, 31122113, 31133113, 31200213, 31211213, 31222213, 31233213, 31300313, 31311313, 31322313, 31333313, 31400413, 31411413, 31921923, 31932923, 32000023, 32011023, 32022023, 32033023, 32100123, 32111123, 32122123, 32133123, 32200223, 32211223, 32222223, 32233223, 32300323, 32311323, 32322323, 32333323, 32921933, 32932933, 33000033, 33011033, 33022033, 33033033, 33100133, 33111133, 33122133, 33133133, 33200233, 33211233, 33222233, 33233233, 33300333, 33311333, 33322333, 33333333, 38400384, 38411384, 39200194, 39211194, 39222194, 39233194, 39300294, 39311294, 39322294, 39333294, 39400394, 39411394, 40000004, 40011004, 40022004, 40033004, 40100104, 40111104, 40122104, 40133104, 40200204, 40211204, 40222204, 40233204, 40300304, 40311304, 40322304, 40333304, 40400404, 40411404, 41000014, 41011014, 41022014, 41033014, 41100114, 41111114, 41122114, 41133114, 41200214, 41211214, 41222214, 41233214, 41300314, 41311314, 41322314, 41333314, 41400414, 41411414$

Most of these are palindromes. The rest can be interpreted as palindromes if $9$'s are treated as $1$'s followed by $-1$'s and $8$'s are treated as $1$'s followed by $-2$'s. However, I do not see a characterization of what palindromes are in this mess.